# How to validate an address of Solana using Python?

Tags: python

I want to know if the address of Solana either is valid or invalid by using Python. How can I do that? Like in web3.py we validate an Ethereum account/address and it returns `True` of`False`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web3.js `new PublicKey('your_address')` to verify if it is a valid public key.

web3.js also provides `PublicKey.isOnCurve(...)` to validate if a public key is on `ed25519` curve. Given there are PDAs in Solana, and that their addresses are valid public key, but are NOT on the curve.

To summarize: If you are able to instantiate, it means it is a valid public key, if you want to know if the address is on the curve, you need to further validate by calling [`isOnCurve(...)`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html#isOnCurve)

Just noticed that you wanted an answer specific to python, depending on the client that you are using, there should be similar methods to use. One that I found is in [solana-py](https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/src/solana/publickey.py), use the PublicKey object to validate.

Comment: Actuall there's no function available in python

Comment: you don't have isOnCurve(), but just try to instantiate by using new PublicKey(...) -> if this throws error, it is not valid.

Comment: solders has `Pubkey.is_on_curve`: https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/api_reference/pubkey.html#solders.pubkey.Pubkey.is_on_curve

Answer (score -1):

The examples in solders don't always work as intended.
This is the current working example:

**address = 'solana address'**

**sol_addr = Pubkey.from_string(address)**

**if sol_addr.is_on_curve():**

*print('passed test1')*

*return*

**if sol_addr.LENGTH == 32:**

*print ('passed test2')*

These are the two major ways of validating a Sol address. Another way is to use the pair, but there are many dexes too on Sol so that won't be too solid.

Comment: 0x0euuejei isn't a valid base58 pubkey, probably better to use a valid one in the example

Comment: Yeah edited to : solana address , for a better understanding

Comment: Also what doesn't work in Solders?

Comment: The example given on solders webpage doesn't include converting the address from a string(Pubkey.from_string('address'), though the API , in venv file houses the example, you need to first convert from a valid string else you won't be able to run the rest of the code on the address. Same with converting to string , Pubkey.string() doesn't work, but Str('address') works perf

Comment: can you share a link to the part of the docs that is incorrect please?